# Matrix decomposition and transformation to a different form

Tags: matrices

I have a matrix ${M_k}$ and it has been decomposed such that,
${M_k}={U_k}^{-1}{M_0}{U_k}$. Then it has made equal to, ${M_k}={U_1}^{-k}{M_0}{U_1}^k$. I need to know what matrix operation has been done to obtain this relationship.
$U_1$ is a 2 by 2 diagonal matrix and ${M_0}$ is a 2 by 2 matrix. k spans from 0 to $m-1$.

Comment: What is $m$ in the last statement?

Comment: $m$ is the number of short fibers. Its just a number. Let's say 10.